# aAuto refresh only div ajax

Tags: ajax

I am trying to make auto-refresh every 5 second to `div` with ajax interval but, i missing something.

This is my div code:

```js
<script>
    function loadlink(){
        $('#chart').load(function () {
            $(this).unwrap();
        });
    }

    loadlink(); // This will run on page load
    setInterval(function(){
        loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
    }, 5000);

</script>
```

```html
<div id="chart" >{!! $chart->script() !!}</div>
```

Comment: You need to use a document.ready block in order to instantiate your *setInterval* function, or it will never run, since it's never initially called.

Answer (score 1):

your code is running u missing jquery file

```js
  function loadlink() {
        console.log("called load link");
        $('#chart').load(function () {
            $(this).unwrap();
        });
    }

    loadlink(); // This will run on page load
    setInterval(function(){
        loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
    }, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart" >{!! $chart->script() !!}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a *document ready* block to instantiate your *setInterval* function for it run.

Example of newer jQuery:

```
function loadlink() {
    $('#chart').load(function () {
        $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

$(function() {
    loadlink(); // This will run on page load
    setInterval(function() {
        loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
    }, 5000);
});
```

or

```
function loadlink() {
    $('#chart').load(function () {
        $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    loadlink(); // This will run on page load
    setInterval(function() {
        loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: How can should i connect with div `id`?

Comment: Depends on what functionality you have. If you truely wish to reload some entire content, you would have to use *AJAX* for example.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors @KINNARI ? If not, it has to do with something else. Could you elaborate on exactly what it is you want to do, and if it is relevant to any HTML code, add that in your question too as code?

Comment: i am getting console result as  `called load link` but when i put another console in `$('#chart').load(function () {`... then nothing is coming

Comment: Then there is something wrong with `$('#chart').load(function () {`... I can't help any further without elaboration and relevant html code. Isn't your `.load()` function also missing the URL parameter? Refer to: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181196/discussion-between-kinnari-and-martin).